# Why does proxy authentication force retries in browser and how to replicate in Java?

Tags: java, http, networking, proxy

I am trying to get an access token from concur's implementation site. In firefox, If I go to the access token site directly and manually enter in the authorization and X-ConsumerKey headers, I get a response.

However, it fails twice with a 407 error - Proxy Authentication Required before finally getting a successful 200 code back with the access token.

[Screenshot of Firefox Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF8gG.png)

In code, I am doing the below. However, I never get a 200 code back like I do in the browser.

```
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

    NTCredentials ntCreds = new NTCredentials("proxyUsername", "proxyPassword","machineLocalName", "domain.com");

    credsProvider.setCredentials( new AuthScope("proxyURL",proxyPort, 
            AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "ntlm"), ntCreds );
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope("targetHostURL", 443),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("serviceAccountName", "ServiceAccountPassword"));

    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("ServiceAccountName", "ServiceAccountPassword");

    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    NTLMScheme ntlmScheme = new NTLMScheme();


    try {
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("targetURL", 443, "https");
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxyURL", proxyPort);

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setProxy(proxy)
            .build();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/net2/oauth2/accesstoken.ashx");
        httpget.setConfig(config);

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine() + " to " + target + " via " + proxy);



        HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

        clientBuilder.useSystemProperties();
        clientBuilder.setProxy(proxy);
        clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
        clientBuilder.setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy());

        HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
        authCache.put(proxy, ntlmScheme);

        context.setAuthCache(authCache);

        context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

        clientBuilder.setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(new ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean retryRequest(final HttpResponse response, 
                    final int executionCount, final HttpContext context) {
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                System.out.println("In retry request with code: "+statusCode);

                return statusCode == 407 && executionCount <5;

            }

            @Override
            public long getRetryInterval() {
                return 0;
            }

        });

        clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = clientBuilder.build();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, context);

        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        } finally {
            response.close();
            httpclient.close();
        }



    } finally {

    }
}
```